# hstack a noise and image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

so when I Hstack the noise to images in the frame, all of the images will be shown broken.
What's the problem with the noise?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("sunset.jpg")
img = np.float64(image)

noise = np.random.randn(*img.shape) * 80  # 80% noise
noisy_img = img + noise
noisy_img = np.uint8(np.clip(noisy_img, 0, 255))

# cv2.imshow("res:", np.hstack([image, noisy_img]))
cv2.imshow("res:", np.hstack([image, noisy_img, noise]))
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental problem: the np.uint8 type.
Uint8 can only store 2^8=256 values in the range [0,255]. If your original image has high pixel values, those pixel can saturate and get clipped at 255 when you use

```
 np.clip()
```

I would recommend reducing the noise intensity.

Answer (score 0):

You must normalize the noise data to integer values (int) as follows:

```
cv2.imshow("res:", np.hstack((image, noisy_img, np.uint8(noise))))
```

Comment: If I have solved your question, I would appreciate if you vote for my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.